# How to flatten Array string column to row in snowflake?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, flatten

I've tried using snowflake's flatten, but it doesn't work, so I'm asking.

Example data

- array string type -> varchar

| id | array string |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [10001,100000][10003,100000000][10004,10000][10006,100] |

I want

| id | array string |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [10001,100000] |
| 1 | [10003,100000000] |
| 1 | ..... |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    id, 
    '[' || c.value::string AS "array string"
FROM data d,
     LATERAL FLATTEN(input=>split(d."array string", '[')) c;
```

should work, as you are splitting on the open array token, and thus need to put it back in the output.

Comment: Thank you very much. Although a separate row is created with only '[', if I filter only it, it comes out exactly as I want.

Comment: @SuyoungJang ah yes, the first `[` becomes it's own result, which I assume would also happen for the trailing `]` if you swap to that. opps, I didn't test the SQL.